# ThreeJS texture is always black using 2D canvas as source for MeshBasicMaterial texture?

Tags: canvas, three.js, textures

I am trying to display a cube with one side showing an image that I draw some text upon.  I've tried several approaches but the side that with the image and text always ends up being rendered as black.  If instead I simply load the image directly using something like the ThreeJS text loader, I can see the image just fine (with no text on it of course).  What is wrong with my code so that I can't see the desired image with the text I print on to it during initialization?

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var SPEED = 0.01;
var cube = null;

var imgBackSide = null;

function init() {
    // Create a document element to house the back side image for cards.
    imgBackSide = document.createElement('img');
    imgBackSide.src = '/images/cards/card-back-side-400x400.png';

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    initCamera();
    initRenderer();
    initCube();

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function canvasDrawText(ctx, canvas, text, x, y) {
    // if x isn't provided
    if ( x === undefined || x === null ){
        let textSize    = ctx.measureText(text);
        x = (canvas.width - textSize.width) / 2;
    }

    // if y isn't provided
    if ( y === undefined || y === null ){
        let textSize    = ctx.measureText(text);
        y = (canvas.height - textSize.height) / 2;
    }

    // actually draw the text
    // ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

function newCardBacksideTexture(cardBackSideText) {
    // Create an IMG element to hold the card back side image and load it.
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;

    ctx.drawImage(imgBackSide, 0, 0);

    // Draw the card label on top of the background.
    ctx.font    = 'bolder 90px Verdana';
    canvasDrawText(ctx, canvas, cardBackSideText);
    // dynamicTexture.texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();

    return new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
}

function initCube() {
    let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 0.1, 2);
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    let dummy = loader.load("/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png");

    let materialArray = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        // Card face.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/card-face.jpg') } ),
        // Card back side.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: newCardBacksideTexture('BACK SIDE OF CARD') } ),
        //
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
    ];

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );
    scene.add(cube);
}

function rotateCube() {
    cube.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
    cube.rotation.y -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateCube();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has 2 issues

1. It's not waiting for the image you draw on the canvas to load so when it tries to draw that image nothing will be drawn.
2. The computation for centering drawing the text in the center references `textSize.height`. There is no such value so `y` ends up being `NaN` and no text is drawn.

Note you can center text easier by asking the canvas to do it.

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
```

Will center text over the draw location

As for waiting for the image to load you'll need to decide how to structure your code to wait. You can either wait for the image to load before starting. Or you can create a canvas and a `CanvasTexture`. Pass that into the cube material, then when the image finished download update that canvas and set the `CanvasTexture`'s `needsUpdate` to true.

```js
var scene, camera, renderer;
var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var SPEED = 0.01;
var cube = null;

var imgBackSide = null;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    initCamera();
    initRenderer();
    initCube();

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function canvasDrawText(ctx, canvas, text, x, y) {
    // if x isn't provided
    if (x === undefined || x === null) {
      x = canvas.width / 2;
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    } else {
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    }
    
    // if y isn't provided
    if ( y === undefined || y === null ) {
      y = canvas.height / 2;
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    } else {
      ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';
    }

    // actually draw the text
    // ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

function newCardBacksideTexture(cardBackSideText) {
    // Create an IMG element to hold the card back side image and load it.
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
    
    const canvasTex = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

    // Create a document element to house the back side image for cards.
    imgBackSide = document.createElement('img');
    imgBackSide.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(imgBackSide, 0, 0);

      // Draw the card label on top of the background.
      ctx.font    = 'bolder 90px Verdana';
      canvasDrawText(ctx, canvas, cardBackSideText);
      // dynamicTexture.texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
      
      canvasTex.needsUpdate = true;
    };
    
    // this is needed only if the image
    // comes from another domain
    imgBackSide.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    
    imgBackSide.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg';

    return canvasTex;
}

function initCube() {
    let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 0.1, 2);
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    let dummy = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png");

    let materialArray = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png') } ),
        // Card face.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png') } ),
        // Card back side.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: newCardBacksideTexture('BACK SIDE OF CARD') } ),
        //
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png') } ),
    ];

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );
    scene.add(cube);
}

function rotateCube() {
    cube.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
    cube.rotation.y -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateCube();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.min.js"></script>
```